# onActivityResult resultCode returning null

Tags: android, firebase, android-intent, firebase-realtime-database

It is a quite a disappointing error for me, below is the implementation for a button click which will choose an image to upload in my firestore, but I'm getting -1 as resultCode.

```
mAddMessageImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Select image for image message on click.
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE);
        }
    });
```

And finally the culprit **onActivityResult**:

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: requestCode=" + requestCode + ", resultCode=" + resultCode);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (data != null) {
                final Uri uri = data.getData();
                Log.d(TAG, "Uri: " + uri.toString());
                FriendlyMessage tempMsg =
                        new FriendlyMessage(null, mUsername, mPhotoUrl, LOADING_IMAGE_URL);
                mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child(MESSAGES_CHILD)
                        .push().setValue(tempMsg, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@Nullable DatabaseError databaseError, @NonNull DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                        if (databaseError == null) {
                            String key = databaseReference.getKey();
                            StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
                                    .getReference(mFirebaseUser.getUid())
                                    .child(key)
                                    .child(uri.getLastPathSegment());
                            putImageInStorage(storageReference, uri, key);
                        } else {
                            Log.w(TAG, "Unable to write message to database.", databaseError.toException());
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        }
    }
}
```

It keeps uploading the placeholder hardcoded image with every button click, Please save me!

Comment: com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@6ae10e7 I'm getting this after calling task.getResult().getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl().toString()

Answer (score 0):

You might try wrapping it in a try/catch block:

```
    try {
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE);
    return true;
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I just saw RESULT_OK value is indeed -1

Comment: What else could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) 
{
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE && resultCode  == RESULT_OK)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want a `resultCode` of -1 since that is [`Activity.RESULT_OK`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#RESULT_OK).